# How to add SwatchLegend to a graph?

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, color, legending

I created a random graph with each vertex colored randomly.

I would like to add a `SwatchLegend` to the graph to indicate the value corresponding to a color. How can I do that?

Here's my code for the graph.

```
color = Map[# -> ColorData[3][RandomInteger[{1, 5}]] &, Range[100]];
g1 = RandomGraph[{100, 500}, VertexStyle -> color, VertexSize -> 1.5]
```

Here's my code for the legends.

```
legend = SwatchLegend[Table[ColorData[3][i], {i, 1, 5}], Automatic];
```

How can I combine the two?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`Legended`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Legended.html):

```
Legended[g1, legend]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use the option `Epilog`:

```
RandomGraph[{100, 500}, VertexStyle -> color,  VertexSize -> 1.5, 
 Epilog -> Inset[legend, Scaled @ {1.1, .5}], ImagePadding -> 40]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In general, you can use any type of legends inside the plotting routines:

```
Plot[
 {Sin@x, Cos@x}, {x, -Pi, Pi},
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue},
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[SwatchLegend[{Red, Blue}, {"Sin", "Cos"}], Right]
 ]
```

However, the **kglr**'s way allows making legends for any objects (like arbitrary graphics).